# Simply post the values of a form to php

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="name[1]"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="gender[1]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="name[2]"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="gender[2]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="name[3]"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="gender[3]"></td>
</tr>
```

And I simply want to post it's values with ajax to get something like this in php:

`var_dump($name)`:

```
array (size=3)
  1 => string 'Brunhilde' (length=9)
  2 => string 'Kevin' (length=5)
  3 => string 'Han Solo' (length=8)
```

`var_dump($gender)`:

```
array (size=3)
  1 => string 'female' (length=6)
  2 => string 'male' (length=4)
  3 => string 'male' (length=4)
```

---

`serialize()` and `serializeArray()` do not what I'm looking for. For example `serializeArray()`:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => array (size=2)
    'name' => string 'name[1]' (length=7)
    'value' => string 'Brunhilde' (length=9)
  1 => array (size=2)
    'name' => string 'gender[1]' (length=9)
    'value' => string 'female' (length=6)
  ...
```

I used to work with xajax, where a single function `xajax.getFormValues()` solved that perfectly.
How do I accomplish that with ajax?

**Update:** The code:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "text",
    url: myUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        myVar1: $("#myVar1").val(),
        myVar2: $("#myVar2").val(),
        myForm: $("#myForm").serializeArray()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: how do you currently post the form values? can we see the code that does that?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Noone seems able to give me the answer that solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class/data-identifier to all the common type data.Example i have added name-text class to all the inputs to capture name

```
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="name-text" name="name[1]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="gender-text" name="gender[1]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="name-text" name="name[2]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="gender-text" name="gender[2]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="name-text" name="name[3]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="gender-text" name="gender[3]"></td>
    </tr>

    var nameValues = Array();
    $('.name-text').each(function(){
    nameValues.push(this.val());
    });

var genderValues = Array();
    $('.gender-text').each(function(){
    genderValues.push(this.val());
    });

    $.post(url,{'name':nameValues,'gender':genderValues},function(){

    });
```

This will send all names under a single variable 'name' to php

Comment: Isn't there an easier built-in solution?